# Lenovo ThinkPad E530 nvidia gt 630m Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have problem with the nvidia drivers. When i update xorg and enable 1 of the 4 posible drivers and restart the screen is becoming small with big icons and this is for every driver i try.
Can someone help me please.
Also many times when i work the screan lag i can not start console, can not move mouse, canot reboot and the only way is "hard way" i must coldly turn off my laptop. The question is : Is this a hardware(in windows 2007 i dont have this problem) or software problem and how to solf it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like for some reason enabling these drivers sets your screen resolution lower. Simply set it to the appropriate resolution using the Displays tool. As for the lagging, if this is an nvidia driver that we are talking about, just search "nvidia" in the dash. I think that the application you want is something like "Nvidia X Server" and one of the options is to set the graphics to high performance mode. It is made to seem as if when you set to high performance, your graphics quality goes down, but when I set mine to high performance there was no noticeable difference. Hope this solves your problem!